# How do create a splitting container in flutter? What should be the right approach? CustomPainter or Chip?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Wanted to replicate some UI. Can I do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxHAW.png) with in built flutter widgets? I have tried using Chip but was not able to. Will CustomPainter be the right thing to use ?

Comment: I think it's CustomPainter widget is the best option. because it's customized widget

Comment: both `CustomPaint` and `ClipPath` can do it for you

Comment: Any examples or demos doing that.. Tried using CustomPaint by didn't get the desired result..

Comment: @DaisyShah I will make example for you

Comment: That would be really helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made `TestPage`, Put it in your app and see the results. Change the Width to keep the shape intact. It's static to three items in the middle and one icon on the left.

If you want to make it dynamic you have to modify the shape in various ways and need optimization

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = 300;
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
          width: width,
          height: width * 0.2442,
          child: CustomPaint(painter: CustomShape())),
    );
  }
}

class CustomShape extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width * 0.8778848, 0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.4401651, 0);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.3433113, size.height * 0.1957085),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1218096, size.height * 0.4987930),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3433113, size.height * 0.1957085);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3109976, size.height * 0.3582477);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.2960634,
        size.height * 0.4332588,
        size.width * 0.2690989,
        size.height * 0.4360304,
        size.width * 0.2538154,
        size.height * 0.3555655);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.2030523, size.height * 0.1251676),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.2818497, size.height * 1.154135),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.1860221, size.height * 0.07393831),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1240584, size.height * 0.5080018),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.1858475, size.height * 0.07393831);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.1858475, size.height * 0.07393831);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.1221152, size.height),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1221152, size.height * 0.5000447),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: true,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.1858475, size.height * 0.9265087),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1213292, size.height * 0.4968261),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.1858475, size.height * 0.9265087);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.2068950,
        size.height * 0.8824318,
        size.width * 0.2298203,
        size.height * 0.7975861,
        size.width * 0.2549071,
        size.height * 0.6654448);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.2707364,
        size.height * 0.5833706,
        size.width * 0.2936617,
        size.height * 0.5869468,
        size.width * 0.3087269,
        size.height * 0.6526598);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3433113, size.height * 0.8046491);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.3433113, size.height * 0.8046491);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.4401651, size.height * 1.000268),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1218532, size.height * 0.4989718),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.8778848, size.height * 1);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.9999782, size.height * 0.5000447),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1220934, size.height * 0.4999553),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 1, size.height * 0.5000447);
    path_0.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.8778848, 0),
        radius:
            Radius.elliptical(size.width * 0.1221152, size.height * 0.5000447),
        rotation: 0,
        largeArc: false,
        clockwise: false);
    path_0.close();

    Paint paint_0_fill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint_0_fill.color = Colors.grey[500]!;
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0_fill);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Write your opinion and tomorrow I'll replay to it.

Comment: I'll try it today.. Also I tried using [link](https://shapemaker.web.app) but didn't optimise it.

Comment: @DaisyShah First I made the shape with illustrator (Don't forget to Simplify the path) , Then export it into SVG. I used [this](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) tool to convert it to flutter `CustomPainter`. Modify it the way you want and I've got the results

Comment: I tried it today and it's working exactly fine.. Thanks